# Did slaves have slaves?

Tags: middle-ages, ancient-history, slavery, early-modern, modern

Was there anywhere in history where the enslaved were able to enslave others?

Was there a slave hierarchy?

I read the [slavery wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery) entry, it mentions that in various cultures people retained some rights while enslaved.

But was there anywhere in the world, anytime in history, where slaves retained enough rights to be slave owners while being enslaved?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Short Answer**

**Yes.** There are examples of slaves owning slaves from different historical periods and in different regions of the world, including:

- **Ancient Near East**
- **Early Medieval Sunni Islam**
- **Late Medieval Mallorca**
- **19th century Brazil and the West Indies**
- **Pre-colonial and colonial East and West Africa**

---

**Details**

**Ancient Near East**

In the [Neo-Babylonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Babylonian_Empire) period (605–333 BC),

> there is a wealth of documentation about slaves, working in three
> capacities. First, there was a small number of royal slaves....Then
> there were slaves as janitors owned by the temples...Finally, the
> largest and best-known group of slaves were those owned by private
> persons. Among them we see great variety in the tasks performed, from
> agriculture to loan-sharking.
>
> ...**The loan-sharking slaves** could become very rich and in some ways quite
> powerful. They could marry in legally recognised weddings and must
> have known the high and mighty who gave them loans. They probably had
> access to amenities that very few free Babylonians could afford, and
> many apparently invested for themselves on the side and so controlled
> their own money as a peculium. They also **owned their own slaves.** But
> they never were allowed to accumulate enough money to buy their
> freedom or the freedom of their loved ones.

*Source: K. Bradley & P. Cartledge (eds), [The Cambridge World History of Slavery, Vol 1: The Ancient Mediterranean World](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287314077_The_Cambridge_world_history_of_slavery_volume_1_The_ancient_mediterranean_world), p.15*

M. A. Dandamaev's key work *[Slavery in Babylonia: From Nabopolassar to Alexander the Great (626-331 B.C.)](https://archive.org/details/SlaveryInBabyloniaFromNebopolassarToAlexanderTheGreat626-331B.C/page/n47)* states that **slaves also owned slaves (and land) during the (earlier) [Neo-Assyrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Assyrian_Empire) period (911 - 609 BC)**.

---

**Medieval Sunni Islam**

Kecia Ali, in *[Marriage and Slavery in Early Islam](https://archive.org/details/KeciaAliMarriageAndSlaveryInEarlyIslam/page/n3)* (Harvard University press, 2010), under a sub-heading 'Slaves Owning Slaves', writes that in [Maliki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maliki) doctrine,

> The [Mudawwana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudawana) considers, for example, a case where a free man swore
> that all his slaves (mamdlik) were manumitted  "and he [the free man]
> has slaves **and his slaves have slaves**." In such a  case, according to
> Malik "only his [i.e., the free man's] slaves are manumitted and his
> slaves' slaves are left in the possession of those of his slaves whom
> he had manumitted, [remaining] enslaved to them ."  Given that
> slaves could own other slaves, Malik granted a male slave  licit
> sexual access to his female slaves, subject to the same restrictions
> as a free owner.

---

**Late Medieval Mallorca**

In late medieval Mallorca, after it had been taken from the Moors by [James I of Aragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_I_of_Aragon),

> there is scattered evidence of Mallorcan freedpersons and slaves
> owning slaves. In 1337, the Greek Serena, from the village of Muro,
> unconditionally manumitted her slave Antonia. At the end of the
> century, **the slave Catalina petitioned for back pay owed to her slave
> Antonio**. The practice continued into the fifteenth century, as when
> the freed Circassian slave Margarita manumitted the four month - old
> daughter of her Bulgar slave in 1404.

*Source: Kevin D. Mummey, '[Women, Slavery, and Community on the Island of Mallorca, ca. 1360-1390](https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/185588)' (Ph.D thesis, 2013)*

---

**West Indies**

Slaves also owned slaves in the West Indies. James Rodway, in *[The West Indies and the Spanish Main](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/32809/32809-h/32809-h.htm)* (1899), contrasted the difference between slaves of rich planters and those owned by poor white men and other slaves.

> the miserable, broken-down creatures **sold cheap as refuse lots to poor
> white men or even to slaves. Yes, the slaves bought their diseased
> fellow-countrymen, to work on their own allotments**, treating them as
> the [costermonger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costermonger) sometimes does his donkey. Half-starved, hard-worked,
> and covered with sores, they lingered in misery until death came to
> make them free. Some were so disfigured with yaws, or leprosy, that
> none but a negro could bear the sight of them; these were kept out of
> the way and treated worse than mangy dogs.

---

**19th Century Brazil**

Mieko Nishida, in *[Slavery and Identity: Ethnicity, Gender, and Race in Salvador, Brazil, 1808-1888](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=8UAwqTtrHE4C&vq=slaves%20owned%20slaves&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* (Indiana University Press, 2003) refers to "**slaves owned slaves**":

> ex-slaves or sometimes even slaves themselves, who did own any other
> form of property owned slaves.

---

**Pre-colonial and colonial East and West Africa**

This is very well documented, partly due to the involvement of Dr. Daniel O’Sullivan-Beare, the Vice Consul on [Pemba Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pemba_Island) in 1895. One early case was that of Mzuri Kwao:

> **Mzuri Kwao became a *mtumwa ya mtumwa*, a slave of a slave**. This is a
> term that is rarely discussed in the literature on enslavement along
> the coast. Yet it comes up several times in the documentation of
> slavery on Pemba. Being the slave of a slave meant that the
> slaveholders had little benefit to offer slaves in terms of social
> status or even security. If slaveholders were enslaved themselves,
> they could not guarantee where their own slaves could live, whether
> they would be resold, and who would inherit them at the death of their
> owner, among other problems. However, the ownership of slaves by other
> slaves indicates the ability of slaves to own property even before the
> British Abolition Decree.

*Source: Elisabeth McMahon, '[Slavery and Emancipation in Islamic East Africa](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Slavery_and_Emancipation_in_Islamic_East.html?id=EbYm0YmfdkoC&redir_esc=y)' (Cambridge University Press, 2013)*

In a footnote, McMahon gives further information and references on slaves owning slaves, also mentioning West Africa

> Prestholdt discussed the concept of **slaves owning slaves as a means to
> remake their status in the society**. Jeremy Prestholdt, *Domesticating
> the World: African Consumerism and the Genealogies of Globalization*
> (Berkeley: University of California Press, 2008), pp. 134–40. Abdul
> Sheriff mentions this in passing for mid–nineteenth century Zanzibar
> Town. Sheriff, 1987, p. 149. Klein notes in passing that is was a
> common system in West Africa; **rather than slaves buying their
> emancipation, they bought their own slaves because it gave them more
> security in old age**. Klein, 1998, p. 13.

---

On **slave hierarchy**, McMahon's book contains a clear example in East Africa:

> Within the social world of slaves there existed a hierarchy based on
> gender, occupation, and the process of enslavement. Slaves of equal
> social status referred to each other as *njoli*. Thus *vibarua* would
> describe each other as *njoli*, but a *kibarua* would not call a *mtumwa ya
> nyumba* a *njoli* because their positions were not socially equal.
> *Vibarua* usually lived in urban centers independent of their owners.
> They paid a daily or monthly wage to their owners, wherein *mtumwa ya
> nyumba* mostly lived in rural areas doing hard agricultural labor under
> the oversight of owners or overseers.

Slave hierarchies were in fact widespread; for further examples, have a look at *[The Diversity of Private Slaving Strategies in Classical Athens](https://www.academia.edu/42049375/The_Diversity_of_Private_Slaving_Strategies_in_Classical_Athens)* and (for Imperial Rome) [Slaves of Slaves: The Complex Status of Imperial Vicarii](https://www.academia.edu/25130774/Slaves_of_Slaves_The_Complex_Status_of_Imperial_Vicarii).

---

**(all emphasis is mine)**

Answer (score 64):

This happened in Roman Times judging by two notes in [*Slaves doing business: the role of Roman law in the economy of a Roman household*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13507480902916837) by Richard Gamauf (2009):

> A Roman slave could hold property which, despite the fact that it belonged to his master, he was allowed to use as if it were his own. All acquisitions based on such a peculium were automatically credited to the master. [...]
>
> 57. Marcian, Rules, book 5: “A peculium is born, grows, wastes away, and dies. So it was quite elegant of Papirius Fronto to liken the peculium to the slave. 1.… it grows by being increased, it wastes away when underslaves die or property gets lost, and it dies when it is taken away.” [...]
>
> 68. Ulpian, Edict, book 29: “If a slave of mine has underslaves, can I deduct from his peculium what they owe me? One must first ask whether the peculia of underslaves are reckoned in the peculium of the principal slave; according to Proculus and Atilicinus, the peculia of underslaves must form part of his peculium as they themselves do. Thus, debts due to me from their master, the principal slave, may be deducted from their peculia as well as from his; debts due from the underslaves themselves may be deducted from their peculia alone; debts from them to the principal slave rather than to me may be deducted from their peculia, like debts due to a fellow slave; but debts due to them from the principal slave will not, according to Servius, be deductible from his peculium, since his peculium includes theirs, although in my view their peculium will be increased just as happens when a master owes something to his slave.”

I've frankly no idea how common it was. Slaves could buy their own freedom back, so it stands to reason that they might want to do that first. Still, the fact that the legal ramifications of slaves owning slaves were being discussed to begin with is a good hint that it wasn't theoretical.

(Aside: in later periods, I wouldn't be surprised if there had been slave owners among the Janissaries and powerful eunuchs in the [Ottoman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_Ottoman_Empire).)

Comment: Roman and Greek slavery, at least within their cities, is much more akin to pre-1970, pre-free-agency professional sports contracts than to American and West Indian *race-based chattel slavery*.

Comment: "*Buying your own freedom back*" risked losing one's employment. It is not necessarily a first priority if one likes the boss, is well paid, and is on a winning team. Roman and Greek slaves were paid.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens not all of them, and probably not always a lot. But yes, buying your freedom would mean losing your job unless your master offered to employ you which was quite common.

Comment: If your master was kind and you had a good gig going, it might make more sense to invest your earnings into other slaves before buying your own freedom. It sounds kind of silly when I say it outloud like that though.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens My understanding was that Roman slavery was not (in general) a permanent condition nor was it inherited.  What you refer to as the American slavery was understood to be the "English system" of slavery (i.e. designed and originally implemented by the British) as opposed to the Spanish system practiced in e.g. Florida prior to it becoming part of the US.

Comment: @JimmyJames - slavery in Rome was indeed not always permanent, manumission was frequent, but it **was** inherited - the children of a slave woman were slaves, regardless of who their father was (not infrequently their mother's master).

Comment: It should also be noted that the condition of your slaves (*unlike* the condition of servants or employees) was an indicator of wealth:  Well fed, well rested slaves were a sign that you could afford many of them, while underfed, overworked slaves was a sign that you could barely afford the ones you did have.  Essentially, a case of "I'm so rich that even my slaves have slaves"

Comment: @Chronocidal: Intuitively I'd expect a slave's occupation correlated a lot more with their well being than their owner's wealth. Think working in a mine, a plantation, or a galley. (But I'm no specialist of Ancient Rome by any stretch.)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy A good point - my comment refers mostly to "household" slaves

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy You wouldn't really see slaves working in mines, though. It's more about the slaves you see when you go for a friendly visit - housekeepers, waiters, cooks, gladiators...

Comment: Buying your own freedom was not a right.  Your master could always refuse it, just as he could refuse to sell you to someone else.  Plus, as a freedman, you were automatically his client, and he your patron, and you were still in his clan, so it was not as if you were cutting loose from him.

Answer (score 3):

More than once I have read the insult "slave of a slave", implying that someone had a very low status.

Of course one cannot be certain that someone who used such an insult knew of actual slaves of slaves in their society, or merely imagined that someone could be so lowly they could be the slave of a slave.

And I believe it was possible for unusually successful slaves to own slaves in many ancient and medieval societies.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://www.classicsunveiled.com/romel/html/slavery.html) on "slave of a slave" in Roman times. "*A slave of a slave was called a vicarius. A slave's property went to his master upon the slave's death.*"