# In Ancient Greece or Rome, could a slave (not an ex-slave) themselves own slaves, apart from the fictional Eumaeus (Odyssey Book 14 lines 450-453)?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, slavery, greece

In Homer's Odyssey the swineherd Eumaeus is a trusted slave of Odysseus' family, having been bought by Odysseus' father Laertes. Yet we are told in Book 14, lines 450 - 453, that Eumaeus himself owns a slave who he bought with his own resources, who waits on Eumeus and his guest:

'At last the swineherd sat to eat. Mesalius served the food - that was the slave bought by Eumaeus in his master's absence, with no help from his mistress or Laertes. He traded him from Taphians'.

This is the only example I have come across from the Ancient Greco-Roman World of a slave owning a slave, and this is a literary or mythical example, not a historical one.

Are there any other instances of it happening in Ancient Greece or Rome?

I know slaves could themselves own slaves in some other cultures, as in some parts of Pre-Colonial Africa. I also know that an ex-slave in Greece or Rome, after they were freed, could own slaves, but what about when they were still slaves themselves?

And what would happen to the 'slave of a slave' if the slave who owned them was sold to a new master?

And what rights, if any, would someone in the position of Odysseus or Laertes as Eumaeus' master have over Eumaeus's own slave?

Note: some people have pointed out that the question 'Could slaves have slaves?' has previously been asked on Wikipedia. With one exception, the answers to that were concerned only with other times and places than Ancient Greece & Rome, which are the subject of my question.

None of the answers dealt with Ancient Greece at all.

One did refer to a theoretical possibility in Roman law, but had no example of it actually happening, nor information as to, if it did actually occur sometimes, how it worked in practice or how common it was. Accordingly, I believe it is worth keeping this question open in case anyone can shed any light on this.

Comment: Does the question [Did slaves have slaves?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/54619/16951) have the answer you are looking for?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Thanks to justCal and cmw for referring me to the related question on this site 'Did slaves have slaves', referring to World history generally, not just ancient Greece and Rome. I have added a note at the end of my question as to how the existing answers to that only partly resolve my query in relation to the Romans, and not at all in relation to Ancient Greece. My query was originally inspired by reading the passage about Eumaeus in Homer's Odyssey, which is of course one of the very earliest surviving works of Greek literature.

Comment: Under Roman law, a slave could have a *peculium* that theoretically belong to his master, but in practice belonged to the slave.  As it is property, it could probably include other slaves.

Comment: Did you find any answer for Ancient Greece?

Comment: @Carlos Martin, no, which is why I was surprised and a little annoyed that the zealots for rule enforcement for its own sake closed this question. I did find elsewhere examples of slaves of slaves in Ancient Rome, confirming that it was not just a theoretical legal possibility, but nothing at all on Ancient Greece, beyond the very early and fictional example of Eumaeus in Book 14 of the Odyssey. However, Mary's point above about the peculium in Roman law and custom seems valid.

Comment: @Timothy Yeah, but the laws about Roman slavery are easy, being (sometimes changed) in the Codex Iustinianus. The laws in Ancient Greece are more interesting because they are more difficult. I was curious if someone had traced the laws of Solon through Aristotle or something like that about slavery.